# looping in python and checking for logic in try/except method

Tags: python, loops, selenium, logic

I am not an expert in python and I am not understanding something that seems very basic to me. Here it goes:

I am using selenium to get a webpage, look for a link in a specific position (in fact the link to the "next page") and if the link is present click on it and start all over. My piece of code is this:

```
check = True
while check:

    #do something

    #check if there is a link to a "next page":

    try:
        nextPageLink=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='pgLinks']/a[3]")

        nextPageLink.click()
        time.sleep(timeToCharge)
    except:
        check = False
```

This code runs only once. It finds the link to the next page, it clicks on it but it not run  the loop again, like if it goes through the code in except and puts the variable check to False.

Any idea why this is so and how I should be doing it?

thanks

Comment: Have you tried adding a `print` statement to the `except` block to see if it's being triggered? @sshashank124 that would make the code only run one time, the OP wants it to keep looping.

Comment: Could the problem be that `link` is not defined before you use it (and should in fact be `driver.get(nextPageLink)`)? In general, its best not to use a bare `except:` statement because then you catch all exceptions, but usually you want to catch a specific one.

Comment: To *click* the link, call `nextPageLink.click()`.

Comment: @user1862963 Building on @IanAuld's comment, you can also extend your `except` clause to `except Exception as e:` and then print out the exception via `print(e)` (or `print e` if you're working with Python 2). That might provide some insight into what's happening, and give you an idea of which exceptions you should really be catching, as per @Daniel Roseman's answer below.

Comment: I've added prints in both try and except blocks: try block works fine and it finds the links and clicks on it; except block also triggered

Comment: @user1862963 If both blocks are triggered this means that your loop runs at least twice...

Comment: @itsjeyd Not necessarily, the code code could be clicking the link and throwing an exception at `time.sleep(timeToCharge)` which would trigger the except block.

Comment: @IanAuld Oops, you're right. Even more incentive to gather more information about the exception that is being thrown :)

Comment: @IanAuld you are right, the exception was being raised there

Comment: @darthbith, what's better: driver.get(nextPageLink) or nextPageLink.click()?

Comment: @user1862963 I have no idea, sorry! You'll have to check the docs or google around :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is probably that you're catching *all* exceptions. Something is probably raising an exception in one of the other lines, and your catch-all clause is being triggered.

Don't do that. Find out which exceptions you're expecting, and only catch them. Anything else is a legitimate error and should bubble up.

Comment: solved, that was the problem, following all you suggestions I founs out there where other exceptions being raised that I was not interested in. Thanks!